# Hey i'm writing a program to decode morse_code and running into an error with an if statement being ignored

Tags: python, if-statement, morse-code

My code is below it is supposed to decode the message but it keeps failing to remove the initial space character from the beginning of the string even though I have an if condition for it and it's really confusing.

Here is the condition to catch this problem

```
elif count == 0 and item == ' ':
   del result[count]
   deleted += 1
```

Here is the full code

```
MORSE_CODE = {'.-': 'A', '-...': 'B', '-.-.': 'C', '-..': 'D', '.': 'E', '..-.': 'F', '--.': 'G', '....': 'H', '..': 'I', '.---': 'J', '-.-': 'K', '.-..': 'L', '--': 'M', '-.': 'N', '---': 'O', '.--.': 'P', '--.-': 'Q', '.-.': 'R', '...': 'S', '-': 'T', '..-': 'U', '...-': 'V', '.--': 'W', '-..-': 'X', '-.--': 'Y', '--..': 'Z', '-----': '0', '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3', '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6', '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9', '.-.-.-': '.', '--..--': ',', '..--..': '?', '.----.': "'", '-.-.--': '!', '-..-.': '/', '-.--.': '(', '-.--.-': ')', '.-...': '&', '---...': ':', '-.-.-.': ';', '-...-': '=', '.-.-.': '+', '-....-': '-', '..--.-': '_', '.-..-.': '"', '...-..-': '$', '.--.-.': '@', '...---...': 'SOS'}

def decodeMorse(morse_code):
    # ToDo: Accept dots, dashes and spaces, return human-readable message
    
    morse_word_list = morse_code.split('  ')
    for wcount, morseword in enumerate(morse_word_list):
        morse_word_list[wcount] = morseword.split(' ')
        for lcount, letter in enumerate(morse_word_list[wcount]):
            if letter == '':
                morse_word_list[wcount][lcount] = ' '
            else:
                morse_word_list[wcount][lcount] = MORSE_CODE[letter]
            
    result = sum(morse_word_list, [])
    
    print(result, end="\n\n\n")
    
    deleted = 0
    
    for count, item in enumerate(result):
        count = count - deleted
        print(count)
        if item == ' ' and count == len(result) - 1:
            del result[count]
        elif count == 0 and item == ' ':
            del result[count]
            deleted += 1
        elif item == ' ' and result[count + 1] == ' ':
            del result[count]
            deleted += 1
        elif item == ' ' and result[count + 1] != ' ':
            pass
        print(result, end="\n\n\n")
            
    return ''.join(result)


print(decodeMorse('      ...---... -.-.--   - .... .   --.- ..- .. -.-. -.-   -... .-. --- .-- -.   ..-. --- -..-   .--- ..- -- .--. ...   --- ...- . .-.   - .... .   .-.. .- --.. -.--   -.. --- --. .-.-.-  '))
```

here is the output log

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 
'D', 'O', 'G', '.', ' ']


0
[' ', ' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 
'O', 'G', '.', ' ']


0
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


0
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


1
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


2
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


3
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


4
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


5
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


6
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


7
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


8
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


9
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


10
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


11
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


12
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


13
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


14
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


15
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


16
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


17
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


18
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


19
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


20
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


21
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


22
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


23
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


24
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


25
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


26
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


27
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


28
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


29
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


30
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


31
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


32
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


33
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


34
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


35
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


36
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


37
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


38
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


39
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


40
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


41
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


42
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


43
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


44
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


45
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


46
[' ', 'SOS', '!', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'Q', 'U', 'I', 'C', 'K', ' ', 'B', 'R', 'O', 'W', 'N', ' ', 'F', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'M', 'P', 'S', ' ', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', ' ', 'L', 'A', 'Z', 'Y', ' ', 'D', 'O', 
'G', '.', ' ']


 SOS! THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
```

## There shouldn't be a ' ' character at the star of this string

Comment: well, you're changing `result` while iterating it. It is expected to result in funny behavior

Comment: also, this is very weird way to get rid of extra spaces.

Comment: instead of the whole `for` loop, just `return re.sub('\s+', ' ', ''.join(result).strip())`

Comment: I just realised you are talking about "Import re". Sorry I forgot to mention I'm doing a coding challenge on a website and it requires you to write the code in native python no external libraries. so I cant use re.sub()

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner single-iteration loop that doesn't manipulate the original string:

```py
def decode_morse(morse_code):
    morse_words = morse_code.split('  ')
    decoded_message = ''
    for morse_word in morse_words:
        morse_letters = morse_word.split(' ')
        for morse_letter in morse_letters:
            letter = MORSE_CODE.get(morse_letter, '')
            decoded_message += letter
        decoded_message += ' '
    return decoded_message
```

`Output: SOS! THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the deleted count. Let me know and I'll add that too?